# Spring Batch JpaPagingItemReader: how to set a query hint?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-batch, hql

I need help because I can't understand how I can set a query hint in the JpaPagingItemReader.

This is the reader definition:

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader" scope="step"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactoryOracle" 
    p:pageSize="${pageSize}" 
    p:queryString="SELECT t FROM test t">
</bean>
```

I need to set an Oracle hint in the queryString but I can't find the right way to specify it.

If I set the hint like this

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(t indexName) */ t FROM test t
```

I got this exception:

```
2018-09-14 08:28:16.035 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter][reportError] - line 1:8: unexpected token: /
line 1:8: unexpected token: /
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1245)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:730)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.createQuery(JpaPagingItemReader.java:112)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JpaPagingItemReader.java:203)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What prevents you from inserting the hint in the `queryString`? For example `p:queryString="SELECT /*+ FULL(test) */ t FROM test t"` .

Comment: I have updated the main post. As you can see it doesn't work...

Comment: Does JPQL support /*...*/ syntax?

Comment: @Andrea Thank you for the clarification. See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JPA provider does not support hints to be defined inline in the `queryString`, you can configure the `JpaPagingItemReader` with a custom  `JpaQueryProvider` instead of a `queryString`. This interface allows you to have control over the creation of the query that will be executed.

In your case, you can use the `JpaNativeQueryProvider` implementation which supports query hints. See its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/orm/JpaNativeQueryProvider.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using JpaNativeQueryProvider I can use query hints!